# Python List Index Error Despite defined

Tags: python, list, text, unicode

How can I resolve this error?
I am using Python 3.5.1

```
formattedData[0] = additionalPrompt + ". " + formattedData[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code is:

```
def formatLine(lineo,additionalPrompt = ""):
    data = re.split("[.)]+",lineo)
    data.pop(0) 
    formattedData = []
    for item in data:
        formattedData.append(item[:-1])
    print(formattedData)
    formattedData[0] = additionalPrompt + ". " + formattedData[0]
    return formattedData
```

The `lineo` variable is a string of text read from a file encoded in unicode.
When I print `formattedData` before the error line it yields

```
['\x00 \x00B\x00o\x00u\x00d\x00i\x00c\x00c\x00a\x00 \x00l\x00e\x00d\x00 \x00a\x00 \x00B\x00r\x00i\x00t\x00i\x00s\x00h\x00 \x00r\x00e\x00v\x00o\x00l\x00t\x00 \x00a\x00g\x00a\x00i\x00n\x00s\x00t\x00 \x00R\x00o\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00u\x00r\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00r\x00e\x00i\x00g\x00n\x00 \x00o\x00f\x00 \x00A', '\x00 \x00C\x00l\x00a\x00u\x00d\x00i\x00u\x00s\x00 \x00B', '\x00 \x00V\x00e\x00s\x00p\x00a\x00s\x00i\x00a\x00n\x00 \x00C', '\x00 \x00N\x00e\x00r\x00o\x00 \x00D', '\x00 \x00G\x00a\x00i\x00u\x00s']
```

which was the expected result. The next line raises the error mentioned above.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If `formattedData` is indeed what you say it is, this should work. There must be something else going on. At least if I try those two lines (set `formattedData` and then execute the line that causes the error), it works as expected.

Comment: Thank you @pushkin !Your approach to the issue helped, every other line in the file that was read was a blank line however this was not shown in text editors.  Many Thanks

Comment: I think you have other problems. Your data seems to be mis-decoded UTF-16BE.  If I `''.join(formattedData)` and decode it correctly, I get `' Boudicca led a British revolt against Rome during the reign of A Claudius B Vespasian C Nero D Gaius'`.  You might want to read a good Unicode tutorial.